# Preventing duplicates when allowing user to populate SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database

So what I am looking to do is have a survey whose answers are populated into an SQL database. One problem I am not sure how to avoid is allowing duplicates into the database.

For example, I want the user to tell us which organization they are representing.

Say one user enters "big brothers and big sisters" and another, from the same organization enters "Big Brothers & Big Sisters". I have a separate Organization table these answers would be populated into. How would I prevent this from creating two separate rows? There are several instances of fill in the blank questions that I foresee this problem occurring with.

Comment: This is quite a big task, and one best handled at the application level.

Comment: Consider that a survey is just that, collecting info for numerical analysis, not driving org inserts!

Comment: Hello welcome to Stack Overflow. This question is not a good format for SO. I would suggest you to read the following links: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you want good answers here consider providing working solution, provided input, expected output and errors if any and we will be glad to help.This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If the answers from the duplicates don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and flag this for re-opening. Thanks!

Comment: You might consider using an auto-complete field that suggests previous database entries that have similar words, ordered by the number of word matches.

Comment: Perhaps if the user has a rep of 2000 surveys submitted they unlock a privilege to edit and group the faulty data

Answer (score 2):

You might try utilizing the Levenshtein algorithm ( https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance ) and some languages (such as PHP) will have methods to utilize this built in. In addition, you'll probably have to build permutations of the input string by using common substitutions (& / and) and try validating the permutations against the database to make sure that it doesn't already exist.

For what it's worth, it might also be a good UI decision to present the user with similar options to make sure that they really did or didn't mean to type in what they did.

Sorry if it's not much help; not sure what your total requirements are. Hope this helps!